# Which countries require you to change your call sign if you change your residence?

Tags: license, callsign

I live in Austria (OE). There we have to change our call sign if we move beyond one of the 9 Austrian federal state's border. For example I lived near Innsbruck (Tyrol) with the sign OE7TKT. I moved to Graz (Styria) for studying - new call sign OE6TKT, next I moved to the capital Vienna - new call sign OE1TKT. Now I live in Klosterneuburg (Lower Austria) and I became OE3TKT.

Are there similar situations in other countries?

I know, in the US, you'll receive a call sign once and keep it as long as you are registered; in Germany (DL) too.

Tom OE3TKT (former OE7TKT,OE6TKT,OE1TKT), KW4NZ

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com Tom!

Comment: South Africa is the same, 6 callsign zones, you have to change call if you move to another zone.

Comment: Unfortunately as interesting as this question is it doesn't lead to a clear answer because there are so many answers it would be better if you could reword this question so that everybody doesn't chime in with a different answer but there's just one correct answer to the question.

Comment: @Rowan Hawkins: We will create an extra answer, where we can list all countries. Isn't that a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

Canada (Industry Canada) also requires amateur radio certificate holders to change call signs when they move to a different call sign prefix area

[RIC-9 — Call Sign Policy and Special Event Prefixes](http://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/smt-gst.nsf/eng/sf02102.html)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the earlier answer : in the British Isles (except the Republic of Ireland - EI), the callsign prefix changes depending on which entity the operator is in.

My amateur callsign in England is G0SWG. If I operate in these entities, here is how I would have to identify myself:

```
England :           G0SWG
Scotland :         GM0SWG
Wales :            GW0SWG
Northern Ireland : GI0SWG
Isle of Man :      GD0SWG
Jersey :           GJ0SWG
Guernsey :         GU0SWG
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Great Britain if ham moves or travel to other area he has to change prefix.

Comment: Yes, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_signs_in_the_United_Kingdom)